# SQL Combining two queries of different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following queries looking at join tables:

```
select scholarship_id as scholId,
       count(scholarship_id) as incompleteCount
from applicant_scholarship
group by scholarship_id
```

and

```
select scholarship_id as scholId,
       count(scholarship_id) as completeCount
from applicant_comp_schol
group by scholarship_id
```

I would like the two queries to be combined and give me a single table with scholId, incompleteCount, and completeCount. Can somebody help with this?

Used the following for my soltuion:

```
  SELECT scholId,
     SUM (completeCount) AS completeCount,
     SUM (incompleteCount) AS incompleteCount,
     SUM (completeCount) + SUM (incompleteCount) AS totalCount
  FROM (  SELECT scholarship_id AS scholId,
               COUNT (scholarship_id) AS incompleteCount,
               NULL AS completeCount
          FROM applicant_scholarship
      GROUP BY scholarship_id
      UNION
        SELECT scholarship_id AS scholId, NULL, COUNT (scholarship_id)
          FROM applicant_comp_schol
      GROUP BY scholarship_id)
  GROUP BY scholId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select scholarship_id as scholId, 
count(scholarship_id) as incompleteCount 
null as completeCount
from applicant_scholarship group by scholarship_id
group by scholarship_id
Union
select scholarship_id as scholId, 
null,
count(scholarship_id) 
from applicant_comp_schol
group by scholarship_id
```

Comment: You might want to consider using 'UNION ALL' instead of 'UNION',  Union on it's own will remove duplicate rows.

Comment: In this particular sql, you must use a union distinct

Comment: There wont be any duplicate rows, but UNION ALL is still better. But I think OP wants one row for each scholarship_id, with both incompleteCount and completeCount.

Comment: @jarlh you are correct, that is what i am wanting, althought union all is not giving me a single row for each scholID with both incompleteCount and completeCount

Comment: In which case, do what AVK says, use it as a view or a subquery, then group by scol_id.  I.e.  Select scholid, sum(completeCount) + sum(incompleteCount) as totalCount from view_AVK group by scholId

Comment: Using your suggestion @JeffUK and avk's answer, I got what I needed. I will edit my question with the solution I got

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have one more table which contains the full list of records, which would be your base (to make sure you catch the "zeroes"). Assuming you do, you can keep your two queries as subqueries that you left-join against:

```
select
    s.scholarship_id
    ,nvl(inc.num_records, 0) incompleteCount
    ,nvl(cpl.num_records, 0) completeCount
from
    scholarships s
left join (
    select
        scholarship_id
        ,count(scholarship_id) num_records
    from applicant_scholarship 
    group by scholarship_id
) inc on s.scholarship_id = inc.scholarship_id
left join (
    select
        scholarship_id
        ,count(scholarship_id) num_records
    from applicant_comp_schol
    group by scholarship_id
) cpl on s.scholarship_id = cpl.scholarship_id
```

If you don't have that actual "scholarships" table that contains everything, then you can build another subquery which unions these two tables together to get the combined unique scholarship_id values, then use that as your base table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a unique identifier in each of your tables, you can use a full outer join to accomplish this:

```
SELECT   COALESCE (aps.scholarship_id, acs.scholarship_id) AS scholid,
         COUNT (DISTINCT aps.applicant_scholarship_id) AS incompletecount,
         COUNT (DISTINCT acs.applicant_comp_schol_id) AS incompletecount
FROM     applicant_scholarship aps
         FULL OUTER JOIN applicant_comp_schol acs
            ON aps.scholarship_id = acs.scholarship_id
GROUP BY scholarship_id
```

Obviously, I'm assuming `applicant_scholarship_id` and `applicant_comp_schol_id` exist. `Scholarship_ID` will not work in those places as it will result in incorrect counts.